# Cannot pass id of the image through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am using Dropzone.js in my code and I upload images immediately to the database via ajax. Also, I have "Remove" button, and when I click on it, it works fine. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
  var base_url = "<?php echo base_url();?>";
  $("div#dropzone").dropzone({ 
    url: base_url + 'cars/addpic',
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    paramName: "files",
    acceptedFiles: "image/*",
    dictDefaultMessage: "<span class='mif-file-upload mif-3x'></span> <br>Faylları seçin görək",
    init : function() {     
            this.on("removedfile", function(file) {
                alert("File " + file.name);
                $.ajax({    
                    type:'post',        
                    url: base_url + 'cars/deletimage/' + '1417.png',   
                    cache:false,      
                    success:function(data){
                      alert("vsyo");
                    }    
                });
            });

        }
  });
</script>
```

However, I do not know how to get and pass the id of just uploaded image instead of `'1417.png'` in the code. How can I pass the id from table to this variable right after uploading the image?

Php code:

```
public function addpic() {
            $manymanyimages = '';
            $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/cars/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg|JPG|PNG|JPEG';
            $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
            $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
            $config['max_size'] = '25000';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $filesCount = count($_FILES['files']['name']);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++) {
                $_FILES['filee']['name'] = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
                $_FILES['filee']['type'] = $_FILES['files']['type'][$i];
                $_FILES['filee']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
                $_FILES['filee']['error'] = $_FILES['files']['error'][$i];
                $_FILES['filee']['size'] = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];
                if (!$this->upload->do_upload('filee')) {
                    // $this->output->set_status_header(500);
                    $this->output->set_output(strip_tags($this->upload->display_errors()));
                } else {
                    $fileData = $this->upload->data();
                    $manyimages = $fileData['file_name'];
                }
            }

            $last_id = $this->db->select('id')->order_by('id',"desc")->limit(1)->get('cars')->row()->id + 1;

            $data = array(
                'img_name' => $manyimages,
                'iki' => $manymanyimages,
                'post_id' => $last_id
            );

            return $this->db->insert('imgs', $data);
        }
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to find the id before sending the ajax request, then use the id as part of the url? Or are you saying the ajax request returns and id which you want to use for something else?

Comment: I want to get the actual id of just inserted image from the database.

Comment: What is this server you're sending the image to? I assume the `data` object contains the id, but without knowing the server I couldn't tell you how to extract it.

Comment: I send it to MySQL table with php

Comment: So you have a PHP server which receives your ajax request and makes a request to the SQL server. The SQL server replies to the PHP server, and the PHP server replies to the browser with a response containing the id. Is this correct? In that case we need to know what exactly the PHP server sends back. Could you post your PHP code?

Comment: I have edited my code

Comment: I assume `$last_id` is the id you want. But this doesn't tell me what the PHP server is returning to the browser. Maybe there's an `echo` command somewhere - I'd need to know the connection between `$last_id` and the `echo` command. I also don't know what `$this->db->insert('imgs', $data);` returns - I don't know what kind of thing `$this` is.But if you know that the PHP server actually works, it would probably be simpler to just test what its response is by connecting to it through `curl` or something.